# Change Modal dialog box option from javascript function

Tags: jquery, dialog, modal-dialog, jquery-dialog

```
<div id="dialog>html form</div>
```

I have a div which contains form on clicking a button i am opening div in a modal

```
$("#dialog").modal({
            backdrop: true,
            keyboard: false,
            show: true
});
```

now I have a button inside the modal, on clicking the button a dialog box will be opened.
If that dialog box opens i want to manipulate the modal options.

```
function upload_images(){   
   if($("#image_upload").is(':visible'))
     {
        $('#dialog').data('modal').options.backdrop = false;
     }
   else{
    $('#dialog').data('modal').options.backdrop = true;
   }
  $("#image_upload").dialog({              
          resizable:false,
          title: "Upload Images",
          modal:true
   });
}
<div id="image_upload>some content</div>
```

I am getting a error on using 
$('#dialog').data('modal').options
error: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined.
Can any one help me out.

Comment: I think you can't change the modal options on-the-fly. The options object is passed to the modal at init time, so it initializes in a certain way, but just changing the original options won't apply them to the modal in real time. You have to destroy your modal instance and re-initialize it with the new options.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
$("#dialog").modal({
            backdrop: true,
            keyboard: false,
            show: true,
            buttons:{
          "Style Button":function(){
             if($("#image_upload").is(':visible'))
             {
               $(this).data('modal').options.backdrop = false;
             }
             else{
               $(this).data('modal').options.backdrop = true;       
             }
      }
});
```

Comment: but i need to change modal options from a javascript function which opens a dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

changing backdrop value to static solves the problem instead of false
$('#dialog').data('modal').options.backdrop = "static";